# Can transient keywords mark a method?

Tags: java, transient

In a java class java.util.Locale, I find that the keyword transient marked a method.

```
 public final class Locale
    implements Cloneable, Serializable
{
    private static class LocaleNameGetter
        implements sun.util.LocaleServiceProviderPool.LocalizedObjectGetter
    {

        public transient String getObject(LocaleNameProvider localenameprovider, Locale locale, String s, Object aobj[])
        {
            if(!$assertionsDisabled && aobj.length != 2)
                throw new AssertionError();
            int i = ((Integer)aobj[0]).intValue();
            String s1 = (String)aobj[1];
            switch(i)
            {
            case 0: // '\0'
                return localenameprovider.getDisplayLanguage(s1, locale);

            case 1: // '\001'
                return localenameprovider.getDisplayCountry(s1, locale);

            case 2: // '\002'
                return localenameprovider.getDisplayVariant(s1, locale);
            }
            if(!$assertionsDisabled)
                throw new AssertionError();
            else
                return null;
        }
```

Can someone tell me why can this be?

Comment: @user85121 can you provide the link where you see that?

Comment: I checked jdk 1.6 source and it doesn't have `transient` keyword

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936803/why-java-methods-with-varargs-identified-as-transient

Comment: @user85121, what version of jdk do you have? This is an important question, in order to check what is going on in the specific source. If this code is the result from a decompiler the author should have mentioned this!

Comment: It isn't in JDK5/6, might have come in between releases or never at all. See http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-5.0/java/util/Locale.java.html and http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/java/util/Locale.java.html

Comment: Seems the author disappeared... :(

Answer (score 51, accepted):

No it can't, it's only valid for fields. You seem to get your source from .class by decompiling. This is the decompiler bug, if you take a look at `java.lang.reflect.Modifier` src you will see that `transient` and `varargs` have the same value

```
public static final int TRANSIENT        = 0x00000080;
...
static final int VARARGS   = 0x00000080;
```

for a field `0x00000080` means `transient`, for a method (your case) it means `varargs`. This is how `getObject` looks like in java.util.Locale src

```
public String getObject(LocaleNameProvider localeNameProvider,
                        Locale locale, 
                        String key,
                        Object... params) {   <-- varargs
```

In .class (bytecode) varargs is represented by Object[] as the last parameter + modifier bit 7 = 1 (0x80). I guess the decompiler is old and simply does not know about `varargs` which is since Java 1.5 so it printed it as `transient`.

Answer (score 6):

If this code has been decompiled it is most likely a result of this: [Why Java methods with varargs identified as transient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936803/why-java-methods-with-varargs-identified-as-transient)

I am quoting from there:

> Sort of an answer can be found in the code of javassist AccessFlag
>
> public static final int TRANSIENT = 0x0080; public static final int
>   VARARGS   = 0x0080; It appears both have the same values. And since
>   transient means nothing for methods, while varargs means nothing for
>   fields, it is ok for them to be the same.

Answer (score 3):

`transient` can only be applied to member variables and not to methods so there is a problem here.

Looking at the variable names in your code - things like `String s` and `Object[] aboj` - it looks like this source has been generated by decompiling the relevant `.class` file.

I think there is a bug in whichever decompiler you're using which is erroneously adding `transisent` to the method declaration.

Answer (score 1):

This has to be a bug. Or some buggy revision? transient is only applied on variables. Can you provide a link where you see that?

Answer (score 1):

Java documentation states that transient keyword is only applied to instance variables so this doesn´t make any sense

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Result<T> implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Boolean  succ;
    private String code;
    private String msg;
    protected T data;

    public Result() {
    }

    public Result(Boolean succ) {
        this.succ = succ;
    }

    
    


    //Can use this here
    @Transient
    public boolean isFail(){
        return !isSucc();
    }
    public boolean isSucc() {
        return succ != null && succ;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).