# java.lang.reflect.Method#getModifiers returns flag outside valid range?

Tags: java, scala, reflection, jvm

The following code:

```
Class.forName("java.lang.String")
     .getDeclaredMethods
     .find(_.getName == "join")
     .get
     .getModifiers & ~(java.lang.reflect.Modifier.methodModifiers())
```

Evaluates to `128`. It seems to me that it *should* evaluate to `0`, because every modifier that's attached to the `java.lang.String#join` method *should* be within the set of `java.lang.reflect.Modifier.methodModifiers()`.

Looking at the constants in `java.lang.reflect.Modifier`, it seems that `128` corresponds to the modifier bit `java.lang.reflect.Modifier.TRANSIENT`. How can a method end up being flagged as `transient`?

Comment: Just as a hint, for questions like this, I'd try to reproduce in plain Java first - I strongly suspect you'll get the same result, and then that's eliminated Scala from the problem *and* made the question more amenable to "just Java" developers.

Comment: The constants within `java.lang.reflect.Modifier` stem from a time when all bits where unambiguous, regardless of whether you are looking at the modifiers of a field, method or class. Since Java 5, this is not the case anymore and the new modifier bit have not been added to that class.

Comment: TIL. But I'd have preferred an Ammonite screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Brief Explanation

There are two flags with the value 0x80 (128), VARARGS and TRANSIENT, as per the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16234127/8041461), so the method is actually a varargs method.

The [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) confirm that this method is varargs, so the flag makes sense

## Worked example

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;

class TestClass {
  public static void main(final String... args) throws Throwable{
    int methodModifiers = Class.forName("java.lang.String")
        .getDeclaredMethod("join", CharSequence.class, CharSequence[].class)
        .getModifiers();

    Field varargsField = Class.forName("java.lang.reflect.Modifier")
        .getDeclaredField("VARARGS");
    varargsField.setAccessible(true);

    int varargsF = varargsField.getInt(null);
    int staticF = Modifier.STATIC;
    int publicF = Modifier.PUBLIC;

    if (methodModifiers == publicF + staticF + varargsF) {
      System.out.println("Correct");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Wrong");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Javadoc for `Modifier` excludes (omits) the table in section 4.6 of the jvm spec for methods. It would be less confusing if they were explicit about what they intended. Comparing 4.5 and 4.6, volatile and bridge are also overloaded.